# Summing a hidden column in DataTables after filtering

Tags: datatables

I have a datatable that has the search box and column searching.  First, how do I call a function after each search, basically after every draw after a search.  In my function, I then want to loop through all the matching records and if column 5 has a value, add it to a counter and if column 6 (which is hidden) has a value, sum that up. I am trying to create a dashboard above the datatable that changes based on the filtered results.

I found this for creating a function when a search happens, but not sure if it fires before or after filtering, but can't get it to work:

```
$("#example").on('search.dt', function() {
```

// do summing here
});

If that is correct, how do I loop through the all the filtered results as indicated above?

Comment: Wow, thanks for the code.  I will be working on this tomorrow.  Will update progress, but this looks excellent!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threw together a quick and dirty example to get you started. Basically, the table on 'draw' function will trigger on a search or filter event. From there you iterate through all of the visible filtered rows using this: `{ filter : 'applied'}`

Run this snippet and search for "New York". Then check the console to see how the data and numbers behave.

[Or this fiddle if you prefer...](https://jsfiddle.net/ninjascott/ont76sfz/34/)

```js
var mytable = new Object();

var tableData = [
    {name: 'Clark Kent', city: 'Metropolis', numCol: '10', numCol2: '6'},
    {name: 'Bruce Wayne', city: 'New York', numCol: '', numCol2: '12'},
    {name: 'Steve Rogers', city: 'New York', numCol: '30', numCol2: '10'},
    {name: 'Peter Parker', city: 'New York', numCol: '44', numCol2: ''},
    {name: 'Thor Odinson', city: 'Asgard', numCol: '55', numCol2: '15'}
 ];

mytable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
    "search": {
        "regex": true
    },
   sDom: 'lrftip',
    data: tableData,
    columns: [
     {data: 'name', title: 'Name'},
     {data: 'city', title: 'City'},
      {data: 'numCol', title: 'Number'},
      {data: 'numCol2', title: 'Hidden Num', visible: false}
    ], 
    columnDefs: [
        { className: "sum", "targets": [2] },
    ]
 });
  
   
mytable.on( 'draw', function () {
    console.log( 'Redraw occurred at: '+new Date().getTime() );
    var myCount = 0;
    var totalSum = 0;
    mytable.rows( { filter : 'applied'} ).every(function (rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
            var data = this.data();
            
            console.log('num1: ' + data.numCol + ' num2: ' + data.numCol2);
            
            if (data.numCol !== '') {
              //Add to counter                
                myCount += 1;
            }
            
            if (data.numCol2 !== '') {
             //Sum it up 
              totalSum += parseInt(data.numCol2); 
            }
            
        });
        console.log('myCount: ' + myCount + ' totalSum: ' + totalSum);
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<div class="table-responsive">

<table id="mytable" class="table nowrap table-hover table-striped dataTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Number1</th>
        <th>Number2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot id="mytableFoot">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Number1</th>
        <th>Number2</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am just doing datatables on a pre-built basic table with a header and footer row.  In your data, you have numCol1 and numCol2.  Is it possible for my to reference the data in that column by column number and if so, how would I do that?

Comment: Would I just skip the data: tableData?  I think I still need the columns defs, correct?

Comment: Thanks again for this!  I was able to figure out how to sum things and reference things.  Works excellent!